# How can I add a callback with form element for a file upload using javascript and Httphandler

Tags: javascript, html, httphandler

I am trying to upload a zip file on server unzip it there and return names of file to client.

Code:

```
 <form id="frmUpload" action="UploadHandler.ashx" method="post">
        <input id="fileUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" accept=".zip"/> 
        <input id="btnUpload" type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
```

Server Code:

```
   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    var uploadedFile=context.Request.Files["fileToUpload"];
    //uploadedFile is then unzipped, filenames are extracted and put in a string 
    // filenames="a,b,c";
    context.Response.Write(filenames);
    }
```

I want to have a callback function at client where I can access this.

I tried a second approach:

```
  $("#frmUpload").submit(function (evt) {
           // evt.preventDefault();
            //var data = $("#frmUpload")[0].serialize(); // returning empty string
            var form = $("#frmUpload")[0];
            var file = form["fileToUpload"].value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UploadHandler.ashx",
                data: "file="+file,
                success: function (result, status, respObj) {

                    alert(result);
                }
            });
    })
```

In this case success callback is getting executed however, at server i don't have file object as the data passed to server is only the path of zip file. How can I pass file object to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the file object to the server. Instead, you should upload the file to the server and then the server unzips the file and sets a flag in session or database indicating that file has been processed.
Meanwhile you can loop an ajax request to the server requesting for file status. 
*Something like this*

```
var i=0;
for(;;){
if(i==1) return;
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "UploadHandler.ashx",
            data: "file="+file,
            success: function (result, status, respObj) {
                if(result){
                alert(result);
                i = 1;
             }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach however, it is not viable. If I put this looping request inside onsubmit event of form then it will never pick up the correct flag as this request is made prior to the action request. How can I attach a callback with the default request made to server when we use an action in a form?